# Can I do a Raid 5 with a SAS6i/R?

Tags: dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, raid5, dell-perc, perc6

I have a PowerEdge 2970 server with a:
SAS6i/R Integrated Controller for PowerEdge 2950/2970, x6 Backplane
http://accessories.dell.com/sna/products/cables/productdetail.aspx?c=ca&l=en&s=corp&sku=330-2277

I just bought 3 hard drives that I plan to use in a RAID Configuration
I believe it's called a Raid 5 Configuration where there's 1 main drive all the stay in Sync.

My question is:  Will the SAS6i/R Integrated Controller work?

Or do I need to buy something like: Dell Perc5I PCI-E SAS RAID Kit for PowerEdge 2970 
http://www.xbyte.com/ProductDesc.aspx?code=CAT_832_25

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the SAS6i/R only supports 2 drives and RAID 0 and 1 so you will need to purchase something else to do RAID 5 with 3 disks.

Comment: Hello, so you are saying I can do a Raid with just 2 drives?
Meaning instant mirroring on the 2 drives? I think 3 was over kill anyway.

Comment: You do can RAID 1 mirroring with a number of drives divisible by two. So yes two drives in RAID 1 will work with your current controller.

Comment: cool thanks, you just saved me $350 :)

Answer (score 0):

The SAS6i/R only supports RAID 0 and 1 for up to 10 devices on two channels.  So you will not be able to create a RAID 5 array with the three drives you have.  You will need the Perc5/6 to do RAID 5.  Call Dell to ensure you get the correct controller and cables to connect to your back plane.